# iOS: How to determine Camera view idle time?

Tags: ios

How to detect camera / device idle time? In my current app, i show a camera view where-in augmented reality detection is happening using a third party framework. In a scenario, i want to detect camera view (launched using AVCaptureView class APIs) idle time, for ex: if the camera is moved to any direction, then i don't want to do any operation. If camera view is not moved within 10 secs, then i need to do some operation. I want to ask, Is there any generic approach to identify whether camera view (launched using AVCaptureView class APIs) or device is idle for some time ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the accelrometer to determive if there was any movement within the last seconds, if there was no considerable movement then the phone was idle

```
- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
{
if(acceleration.x > someValue || acceleration.y > someValue ||acceleration.z > someValue)
     {
         NSLog(@"you moved the phone");
     } 
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks. Is there any other way, if i don't want to use accelerometer based detection?

Comment: no, i dont think there is any other way, to detect idle movement. if you want you can detect touch idle, thru `touchesBegan:` method